# Four Fermion Interactions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, grassmann-numbers

Given an action with a term like 
\begin{equation}S_{I}\sim \int\int (\psi^{\dagger}\psi)V(\psi^{\dagger}\psi)\end{equation}
How do you evaluate this with a Fermionic path integral?
I know the fields are Grassmann valued so does that mean that
\begin{equation}e^{-S_{I}}=1-S_{I}\end{equation}
because higher powers of $\psi$ and $\psi^{\dagger}$ are zero?
The reason I'm confused is that there is an integral involved, so when you consider $n$ powers of the action, you have to do $n$ integrals over $n$ different regions of spacetime. (i.e. is $(S_{I})^{n}=0$ for $n>1$?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful that there are some integrals, which implies that $S_I^n\neq 0$ !
For instance

$S_I^2=\int_{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4} (\psi_1^\dagger\psi_1)V_{12}(\psi_2^\dagger\psi_2)(\psi_3^\dagger\psi_3)V_{34}(\psi_4^\dagger\psi_4)$,

where $\psi_i=\psi(x_i)$, $V_{ij}=V(x_i,x_j)$ and I assumed that the interaction is of the form $S_I=\int_{x_1,x_2}\psi^\dagger(x_1)\psi(x_1)V(x_1,x_2)\psi^\dagger(x_2)\psi(x_2)$.

Thus, for most values of $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ the integral is not zero (because the Grassmann fields take different values). Only for $x_1=x_2$, etc. you will find that it vanishes. If it wasn't the case, fermions would be really trivial...